# Finding a function given as a part of a convolution integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, laplace-transform, convolution

I am trying to solve the following equation for the function $f$.

$$t^{-\alpha} \exp{ \left(- \beta  x^2 t^{-2 \alpha} \right)} = \int_0^t \frac{f\left(x, s\right)}{t - s}ds$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are some non negative constants.

I have tried to take Laplace and Fourier transforms of the left hand side, but I believe those integrals do not converge. Is there any other strategy to obtain $f$ ?
I am stuck here, any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Differentiate w.r.t t, apply second fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: RHS is the Hilbert Transform of $f(x,t)u(t)$. so i think for finding $-f(x,t)$ you have to calculate Hilbert Transform of LHS.

Comment: maybe substitute $t^{-\alpha} = k$ and see what happens

Comment: @K.K.McDonald, Thank you for the pointer, I am not familiar with Hilbert Transform, one thing sort of concerns me though is that, the right hand side has a finite integral.

Comment: hmmmm.   (.___.') you are right. this is truncated Hilbert transform and i have no clue how to reverse it.

Comment: Ok, I truly have no idea how to solve this integral equation, because everything I try leads to diverging expressions

Comment: I don't know if it helps or not, but if we introduce new parameters: $$\sqrt{\beta} x=p,~~~~t^\alpha=q$$ we have on the left-hand-side: $$\frac{1}{q}e^{-p^2/q^2}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{ \pi}} \int_0^\infty \cos(2pz) e^{-q^2 z^2} dz$$